# Find the smallest positive integer $N$ such that $z^N$ is a real number

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose that $|z(1 + i)|=\sqrt{32}$ and $\arg( (1−i)/z) = \pi /6.$

I have worked out $|z|=4$ and $\arg(z)= -5\pi /12.$

$\arg((1-i)/z)= \pi /6$

$\arg(1 -i) - \arg(z) = \pi /6$

$\ (-\pi /4) - \arg(z) = \pi /6$

$\ (- \arg(z)) = π/6 + \pi /4$

$\arg(z) = - \pi /6 - \pi /4$

$\arg(z) = -5\pi /12$

I am stuck on how to proceed from here on to find smallest positive integer $N$ such that $z^N$ is a real number.

Comment: Are you sure $\arg z=\pi/12?$ How did you find that? (Please answer by editing your post rather than by a comment)

Comment: I found that your two equations are actually incompatible.

Comment: My bad, I have amended it.

Comment: Please edit your post to correct the hypothesis,so as to make them compatible: replace $1-i/z$ with $(1-i)/z.$ And [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation): mainly: put a dollar sign on each side, and a \ in front of arg.

Comment: $w$ is real if and only if $\arg w$ is an integral multiple of $\pi$. Can you express $\arg z^N$ in terms of $\arg z$? Then can you determine when $\arg z^N$ is an integral multiple of $\pi$?

Comment: ...and you are done. Incidentally, note that the first equation (equivalent to $|z|=4$) was actually useless here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to know that multiplying two complex numbers has the effect of *adding* their arguments together. Assuming you've done all of the arithmetic correctly to deduce $\arg(z) = -5\pi/12$, we need to make the following observation: every non-zero real number will have what as its argument? If a real number is positive, we might say its (principal) argument will be $0$. But other values of the argument could be $2\pi, -2\pi,  4\pi, -4\pi, \ldots$ and so on. If a real number is negative, then values of the argument could be $\pi, -\pi, 3\pi, -3\pi, \ldots$ and so on. So really, $z^N$ will be a non-zero real number iff its argument is an integer multiple of $\pi$.

With this in mind, we know that multiplying $z$ by itself $N$  times has the effect of adding $\arg(z) = -5\pi/12$ to itself $N$ times. That is, $\arg(z^N) = \arg(z) + \ldots + \arg(z)$ ($N$ times). If we add $\arg(z)$ to itself enough times to get an integer multiple of $\pi$, then we will know that $z^N$ must be a real number (by our observation from above). So, what is the least number of times you need to add $-5\pi/12$ to itself before you get an integer multiple of $\pi$?